# VBA ArrayFormula too long

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying for a long time to insert the array formula using vba but it is too long, so I split it using replace function. But replace does not still change the formula accordingly.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my initial working formula: `{=IF(IFERROR(INDEX($F:$F;AGGREGATE(15;6;ROW($C$2:$C$1203)/($C$2:$C$1203=$J2);COLUMNS($F$1:F$1)));"")&" "&IFERROR(INDEX($E:$E;AGGREGATE(15;6;ROW($C$2:$C$1203)/($C$2:$C$1203=$J2);COLUMNS($E$1:E$1)));"")=$F2&" "&$E2;"dieselbe Person";IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(INDEX($E:$E;AGGREGATE(15;6;ROW($C$2:$C$1203)/($C$2:$C$1203=$J2);COLUMNS($E$1:E$1)));"")&" "&IFERROR(INDEX($F:$F;AGGREGATE(15;6;ROW($C$2:$C$1203)/($C$2:$C$1203=$J2);COLUMNS($E$1:E$1)));"");"ß";"ss");"ö";"oe");Sheet2!$A:$B;2;FALSE);""))}`

Here is a respective VBA Code:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim sht As Worksheet


Dim formulapart2 As String

Dim formulapart3 As String

Dim rng As Range

shtName = InputBox("Respective Sheetname:")

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shtName)

formulapart2 = "INDEX(C6,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(R2C3:R1203C3)/(R2C3:R1203C3=RC10),COLUMNS(R1C6:R1C[-6])))"

formulapart3 = "INDEX(C5,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(R2C3:R1203C3)/(R2C3:R1203C3=RC10),COLUMNS(R1C5:R1C[-7])))"

Set rng = sht.Range("L2:O11")

rng.FormulaArray = "=IF(IFERROR(""F2"","""")&"" ""&IFERROR(""F3"","""")=RC6&"" ""&RC5,""dieselbe Person"",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(""F4"","""")&"" ""&IFERROR(""F5"",""""),""ß"",""ss""),""ö"",""oe""),Sheet2!C1:C2,2,FALSE),""""))"

rng.Replace """F2""", formulapart2, xlPart

rng.Replace """F3""", formulapart3, xlPart

rng.Replace """F4""", formulapart3, xlPart

rng.Replace """F5""", formulapart3, xlPart


End Sub
```

Actually this code does not entail any error but replace function just does not change the formula.

Comment: Are you sure that formula needs to be array entered?

Comment: In VBA it is unfortunately not allowed to enter array formula longer than 255 characters

Comment: Formula works without problems when being entered directly in excel

Comment: - Use defined names to shorten parts your formula; - Try to shorten the formula itself; - (and try to avoid IFERROR whenever possible, worse funktion ever, but that's my opinion.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the formula parts you are trying to pass are expressed using the R1C1 notation while the formula that is already in the range is probably expressed in A1 notation.

I'm using the term "probably" because that's most likely the setting that you have for your Excel formulas, so after running the line

```
rng.FormulaArray = "=IF(IFERROR(""F2"","""")&"" ""&IFERROR(""F3"","""")=RC6&"" ""&RC5,""dieselbe Person"",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(""F4"","""")&"" ""&IFERROR(""F5"",""""),""ß"",""ss""),""ö"",""oe""),Sheet2!C1:C2,2,FALSE),""""))"
```

the formula is converted to an A1-style formula and it prevents your `Replace` method to work the way you expect it.

One way to solve this would be to set the reference style to R1C1 at the begging of your code and revert back to A1 at the end like this:

```
Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1

' You code

Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1
```